# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null from virtuemart custom field

Tags: undefined, virtuemart

first of all, sorry for my bad English. I got some problem, and I need all of your help!!
I am trying to add custom fields in my product page, but when I select custom field from the list, it appears nothing in the screen and it adds up nothing to my product page. when I check the issue with chrome developer tools, it says 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null                   index.php:1917
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property'value' of null                    index.php:2180
(anonymous function)                                                       index.php:2180
e.resolveWith                                                              jquery.min.js:2
w                                                                          jquery.min.js:4
d                                                                          jquery.min.js:4.

at index.php

```
2179 function(data) {
2180            jQuery.each(data.value, function(index, value){
2181                jQuery("#custom_field").append(value);
2182                jQuery('#custom_field').trigger('sortupdate');
2183            });
        });
```

Everything was working fine, before I tuned up my j-query easy plugins. I added one screenshot to my question. how can i solve this problem?

By the way, I am using Joomla! 2.5.9 and virtuemart 2.0.18a.

In advance Thanks for any help!!!
Asif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of this, it looks like data is undefined; wherever you pass data into the function, it's passing a null value into it. Check everywhere you call it; the problem will be found there.

Comment: I apologize to say this, that I do not know javascirpt, could you please tell me a little brief about this matter, please?